# Python - converting a JSON read file into a usable DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and was trying to use the following code to read in a JSON file and convert it to a dataframe with column headers etc. I just cannot seem to understand what I am doing wrong here as the output is as shown below

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

other_path = "c:\\users\\xyz\\documents\\covid.json"
df = pd.read_json(other_path)
print (df.head())
print (type (df))
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the argument `orient="records"` see the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

```
df = pd.read_json(other_path, orient="records")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding - I tried that and it still shows the same output as before.  Just can;t get it to work.

Comment: @John Could you edit your answer to include the input json structure, in a code block at the top?